# PHP tests pass locally but fail on Travis CI using Composer, PSR-4 autoload

Tags: php, phpunit, travis-ci, psr-4

Could anyone help me understand the reasons that why these unit tests are failing at CI while they pass on local setup.

The repository is at https://github.com/jabranr/test-ci

The tests are at https://travis-ci.org/jabranr/test-ci

The tests fail in CI with a fatal error saying: `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'JRI\JabranCI\Exception\FooBarException' not found in /home/travis/build/jabranr/test-ci/test/exception/FooBarExceptionTest.php on line 11`

The package uses the PSR-4 autoloading. Here is the [composer.json](https://github.com/jabranr/test-ci/blob/master/composer.json) and [phpunit configuration](https://github.com/jabranr/test-ci/blob/master/phpunit.xml). Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So I figured that these tests are failing because names of directories do not match the PSR-4 autoload **case sensitive scheme**.

In this particular case, this was directly related to **case insensitive** nature of OSX. While the unit tests worked fine and passed on an OSX local machine, they kept failing on Travis CI as it bases the tests on Linux (Ubuntu) containers.

So basically from above example, when calling `JRI\JabranCI\Exception\FooBarException`, directory structure should be `src/JRI/JabranCI/Exception/FooBarException.php`

**Generic example:**

If there is a class `Baz` with namespace `Foo\Bar` then using PSR-4 a valid directory structure is `src/Foo/Bar/Baz.php`. The directory structure of `src/foo/bar/Baz.php` is invalid in such a case.